# ActiveRecord - Copying join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I am running a rake task to copy over some live data for demo purposes. One part happens to be taking a very long time to run. Models look something like this:

```
class Host
  has_many :event_attendees, inverse_of: :host, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :events, -> { distinct }, through: :event_attendees
end
```

```
class Attendee
  has_many :event_attendees, inverse_of: :attendee, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :events, through: :event_attendees
end
```

```
class Event
  has_many :event_attendees, inverse_of: :event, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :attendees, through: :event_attendees
end
```

```
class EventAttendee
  belongs_to :event, inverse_of: :event_attendees, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :attendee, inverse_of: :event_attendees, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :host, inverse_of: :event_attendees, dependent: :destroy
end
```

I am copying Hosts, Attendees, and Events while keeping track of their ids (to copy existing EventAttendees). This seems to run fine.

```
def copy_events
    log("Copying events...")

    @event_ids_h = {}

    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do

      Event.
        where(organization_id: source_org_id).
        distinct.
        find_in_batches do |events|
          fake_events = events.map do |event|
            atts = event.attributes.except('id').merge(
              ...atts
            )
            Event.new(atts)
          end

          Event.import(
            fake_events,
            validate: true,
            timestamps: false,
          )

          @event_ids_h = @event_ids_h.merge(Hash[events.map(&:id).zip(fake_events.map(&:id))])
        end
    end
  end
```

The next part works... but it is taking forevvvvver. About 2.5 hours on about 600,000 records.

```
def copy_event_attendees
    log("Copying event attendee data...")

    arr = EventAttendee.
      where(attendee_id: @attendee_ids_h.keys, event_id: @event_ids_h.keys, host_id: @host_ids_h.keys).
      pluck(:attendee_id, :event_id, :host_id).
      map{ |ids| build_event_attendee_row(ids) }

    unless arr.empty?
      values_s = Arel::Nodes::ValuesList.new(arr).to_sql

      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.insert(<<~SQL)
        INSERT INTO event_attendees (attendee_id, event_id, host_id, created_at) #{values_s}
      SQL
    end

  end

def build_event_attendee_row(ids)
  ids[0] = @attendee_ids_h[ids.first]
  ids[1] = @event_ids_h[ids.second]
  ids[2] = @host_ids_h[ids.third]
  ids.push(Time.current)
end
```

I'm *guessing* that it's the `WHERE IN` that is taking so long. But I'm not sure and I'd really like to figure out a way to optimize this if possible.

Comment: Do you have any database indexes on the event_attendees table? How does it take for this query to finish? You can check this in the log file. Try doing `EventAttendee.where(attendee_id: @attendee_ids_h.keys, event_id: @event_ids_h.keys, host_id: @host_ids_h.keys).explain` to see how the query execution plan looks like.

Comment: @KamilGwóźdź yes there are indexes on `attendee_id`, `host_id`, and `(event_id,host_id,attendee_id) UNIQUE`

Comment: How long does it take for the query to finish? Maybe the `map{ |ids| build_event_attendee_row(ids) }` is taking so long?

Comment: @KamilGwóźdź `build_event_attendee_row` does lookup the ids in mem. But when running the script, based on the heroku logs that I'm tailing, it's the query that is taking a long time (~2.5 hrs). I don't have all the ids available to manually look at the query plan, but with a few fake arrays it looks something like this
`Index Scan using index_event_attendees_on_attendee_id on event_attendees  (cost=0.08..8.39 rows=1 width=46)
   Index Cond: (attendee_id = ANY ('{9,8,7}'::bigint[]))
   Filter: ((event_id = ANY ('{3,2,1}'::bigint[])) AND (host_id = ANY ('{1,2,3}'::integer[])))`

Comment: The query execution plan heuristic and it depends on the data you have, in your small dataset index were used but for a big array you can get a sequential scan instead. But it's still unlikely that this query would take 2.5h. Can you share the heroku logs?